# Multithread or multiprocess

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

This is my code:

```
from database_function import *
from kiteconnect import KiteTicker
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import schedule
import time
from multiprocessing import Process



def tick_A():

    #credentials code here

    tokens = [x[0] for x in db_fetchquery("SELECT zerodha FROM script ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50")] #FETCHING FIRST 50 SCRIPTS TOKEN
    #print(tokens)

    ##### TO MAKE SURE THE TASK STARTS AFTER 8:59 ONLY ###########
    t = datetime.today()
    future = datetime(t.year,t.month,t.day,8,59)
    if ((future-t).total_seconds()) < 0:
        future = datetime(t.year,t.month,t.day,t.hour,t.minute,(t.second+2))
    time.sleep((future-t).total_seconds())
    ##### TO MAKE SURE THE TASK STARTS AFTER 8:59 ONLY ###########


    def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
        global ltp
        ltp = ticks[0]["last_price"]
        for tick in ticks:
          print(f"{tick['instrument_token']}A")
          db_runquery(f'UPDATE SCRIPT SET ltp = {tick["last_price"]} WHERE zerodha = {tick["instrument_token"]}') #UPDATING LTP IN DATABASE
          #print(f"{tick['last_price']}")


    def on_connect(ws, response):
        #print(f"response from connect :: {response}")
        # Subscribe to a list of instrument_tokens (TOKENS FETCHED ABOVE WILL BE SUBSCRIBED HERE).
        # logging.debug("on connect: {}".format(response))
        ws.subscribe(tokens)
        ws.set_mode(ws.MODE_LTP,tokens) # SETTING TOKEN TO TICK MODE (LTP / FULL / QUOTE)

    kws.on_ticks = on_ticks
    kws.on_connect = on_connect
    kws.connect(threaded=True)

    #####TO STOP THE TASK AFTER 15:32 #######
    end_time = datetime(t.year,t.month,t.day,15,32)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        #time.sleep(1)
        if datetime.now() > end_time:
          break
    #####TO STOP THE TASK AFTER 15:32 #######


def tick_B():

everything remains the same only tokens value changes

    tokens = [x[0] for x in db_fetchquery("SELECT zerodha FROM script ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET (50) ROWS FETCH NEXT (50) ROWS ONLY")]


def tick_C():

everything remains the same only tokens value changes

    tokens = [x[0] for x in db_fetchquery("SELECT zerodha FROM script ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET (100) ROWS FETCH NEXT (50) ROWS ONLY")]




if __name__ == '__main__':
    def runInParallel(*fns):
      proc = []
      for fn in fns:
        p = Process(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
      for p in proc:
        p.join()

    runInParallel(tick_A , tick_B , tick_C)
```

So, currently, I am using multiprocessing to run these 3 functions together.

As only tokens changes, is it recommended to switch to multi-threading? (if yes, will it really help in a performance like speed-up and I think memory will be for sure used less)

Comment: A thing to consider is that threads in CPython are limited by the GIL. Multithreading with the standard implementation is best used only for I/O-heavy uses. For database manipulation, that likely depends on the database and what exactly what you're doing with it. Multithreading will work well with disk-access since that isn't CPU intensive, but not processing of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general threads are lighter than process, they consume less memory and less resources. However, you need to measure this in your use case(program or system) and see what works for you. If your program wants to share the same memory space use threads, but bear in mind that you will need to protect the memory with semaphores or some locking system.